# Add table column count html

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I am having a problem on how can I add column number when I print data table on my html. Is there any expert can give me  way or solution to add it when I click the button prints? Please see attachment below for reference and the image below is what I want and looks like.
Thanks in advance!
This is what I want:
[image: SAMPLE]

**HTML Code:**

```html
<button onclick="printDiv();">Print it</button>
<table class="report-container" name="table" id="table">

  <thead class="report-header">
    <th colspan="9">
      <div class="titles">Hello World <br></div>
    </th>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample</td>
      <td>Sample</td>
      <td>Sample</td>
      <td>Sample</td>
      <td>Sample</td>
      <td>Sample</td>
      <td>Sample/thumb</td>
      <td>Sample &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td>data</td>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="9">
     <div class="footer">Footer</div>
    </th>
      </tr>
  </tfoot>

  <tbody class="report-content">
   
    <tr>
      <td class="report-content-cell">
        <div class="main">
          data 1
      </td>
      <td> data 2</td>
      <td> data 3</td>
      <td> data 4</td>
      <td> data 5</td>
      <td> data 6</td>
      <td> data 7</td>
      <td> data 8</td>
      <td> data 9</td>

    </tr>
   
   <tr>
      <td class="report-content-cell">
        <div class="main">
          data 1
      </td>
      <td> data 2</td>
      <td> data 3</td>
      <td> data 4</td>
      <td> data 5</td>
      <td> data 6</td>
      <td> data 7</td>
      <td> data 8</td>
      <td> data 9</td>

    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="report-content-cell">
        <div class="main">
          data 1
      </td>
      <td> data 2</td>
      <td> data 3</td>
      <td> data 4</td>
      <td> data 5</td>
      <td> data 6</td>
      <td> data 7</td>
      <td> data 8</td>
      <td> data 9</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="report-content-cell">
        <div class="main">
          data 1
      </td>
      <td> data 2</td>
      <td> data 3</td>
      <td> data 4</td>
      <td> data 5</td>
      <td> data 6</td>
      <td> data 7</td>
      <td> data 8</td>
      <td> data 9</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="report-content-cell">
        <div class="main">
          data 1
      </td>
      <td> data 2</td>
      <td> data 3</td>
      <td> data 4</td>
      <td> data 5</td>
      <td> data 6</td>
      <td> data 7</td>
      <td> data 8</td>
      <td> data 9</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="report-content-cell">
        <div class="main">
          data 1
      </td>
      <td> data 2</td>
      <td> data 3</td>
      <td> data 4</td>
      <td> data 5</td>
      <td> data 6</td>
      <td> data 7</td>
      <td> data 8</td>
      <td> data 9</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="report-content-cell">
        <div class="main">
          data 1
      </td>
      <td> data 2</td>
      <td> data 3</td>
      <td> data 4</td>
      <td> data 5</td>
      <td> data 6</td>
      <td> data 7</td>
      <td> data 8</td>
      <td> data 9</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="report-content-cell">
        <div class="main">
          data 1
      </td>
      <td> data 2</td>
      <td> data 3</td>
      <td> data 4</td>
      <td> data 5</td>
      <td> data 6</td>
      <td> data 7</td>
      <td> data 8</td>
      <td> data 9</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="report-content-cell">
        <div class="main">
          data 1
      </td>
      <td> data 2</td>
      <td> data 3</td>
      <td> data 4</td>
      <td> data 5</td>
      <td> data 6</td>
      <td> data 7</td>
      <td> data 8</td>
      <td> data 9</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="report-content-cell">
        <div class="main">
          data 1
      </td>
      <td> data 2</td>
      <td> data 3</td>
      <td> data 4</td>
      <td> data 5</td>
      <td> data 6</td>
      <td> data 7</td>
      <td> data 8</td>
      <td> data 9</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="report-content-cell">
        <div class="main">
          data 1
      </td>
      <td> data 2</td>
      <td> data 3</td>
      <td> data 4</td>
      <td> data 5</td>
      <td> data 6</td>
      <td> data 7</td>
      <td> data 8</td>
      <td> data 9</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="report-content-cell">
        <div class="main">
          data 1
      </td>
      <td> data 2</td>
      <td> data 3</td>
      <td> data 4</td>
      <td> data 5</td>
      <td> data 6</td>
      <td> data 7</td>
      <td> data 8</td>
      <td> data 9</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="report-content-cell">
        <div class="main">
          data 1
      </td>
      <td> data 2</td>
      <td> data 3</td>
      <td> data 4</td>
      <td> data 5</td>
      <td> data 6</td>
      <td> data 7</td>
      <td> data 8</td>
      <td> data 9</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Java Script:

```html
<script ="text/javascript">
    function printDiv() {
  let tbl = document.getElementById('table');
  let footer = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tfoot')[0];
  footer.style.display = 'table-row-group';
  tbl.removeChild(footer);
  tbl.appendChild(footer);

  // Make header visible on first page only
  let title = document.querySelector('.titles');
  let newTitle = title.cloneNode(true);
  newTitle.style.textAlign = "center";
  newTitle.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  tbl.prepend(newTitle);
  title.remove();

  var divToPrint = document.getElementById('table');
  var htmlToPrint = '' +
    '<style type="text/css">' +
    'table td {' +
    'border:1px solid #dddddd;' +
    'padding:8px;' +
    '}' +

    'table  {' +
    'border-collapse: collapse;' +
    'width: 100%;' +
    '}' +
    '</style>';
  htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
  newWin = window.open("");
  newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
  newWin.print();
  newWin.close();
}
</script>
```

CSS:

```html
<style type="text/css">
@media screen {
  .noPrint {}

  .titles {
    display: none;
  }

  .footer {
    display: none;

  }
}

@media print {
  .noPrint {
    display: none;
  }

  .title {}

  .footer {}
}
    
</style>
```

Comment: You should have a look at [css counters](https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_counters.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

more simple is [css counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)

code

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 11px;
  counter-reset: noElm;
}
th,
td {
  padding: .2em .7em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tbody tr {
  counter-increment: noElm;
}
td:nth-of-type(1):before {
  content: counter(noElm);
}
th:nth-of-type(1),
td:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}
@media print {
  th:nth-of-type(1),
  td:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: table-cell;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption> Hello World </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>No</th><th>name1</th><th>name2</th><th>name3</th><th>name4</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td></td><td>lib 1</td><td>lib 2</td><td>lib 3</td><td>lib 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>lib 1</td><td>lib 2</td><td>lib 3</td><td>lib 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>lib 1</td><td>lib 2</td><td>lib 3</td><td>lib 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>lib 1</td><td>lib 2</td><td>lib 3</td><td>lib 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>lib 1</td><td>lib 2</td><td>lib 3</td><td>lib 4</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```